# How do I set the time duration of an animation using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I want a JavaScript function to take the time I provide to execute.
I know what `setTimeOut()` or `setInterval()` does, I am not looking for them.

For example, I have a `div` at `top: 0` and `left: 0`.
I want my JS function to take the `div` from `left: 0` to `left: 50` in the given time.

Please provide a raw JavaScript solution, not jQuery.

Comment: you want a css transition instead

Comment: You don't mean that you want to set duration of a function, you mean you want to set duration of an animation. And the "traditional" way to implement animation in JS is with `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`, so actually you are looking for them. (Or perhaps you are looking for the more up-to-date `requestAnimationFrame()` method, but the underlying principle is more or less the same.) Or of course you may want a CSS transition as already suggested.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted, but if I do `display:hidden;` or `display:inline;`  the transition is not visible, right ? how do I get that with JS ? And yes, will `setTimeout()` be able to do the transition ? or it will just wait till the provided time passes and then make the move suddenly ?

Comment: @Towkir: What people do is setTimeout to wait for a small (0.1 second or so) time passes then make one small move suddenly and then repeat for 100 times or so to make the animation 10 seconds (0.1 x 100 = 10 seconds). BTW. That's how TV and cinema work. For cinema, the film projector waits for a small amount of time then suddenly project another picture onto the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Animations defines the experimental [`Element.animate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ca/docs/Web/API/Element/animate)

```js
document.getElementById("test").animate([
  { left: '0px' }, 
  { left: '50px' }
], {
  duration: 1000,
  fill: 'forwards'
});
```

```css
#test {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: did you see the error while running the code snippet  ?

Comment: @Towkir Probably your browser does not support it yet, it's an experimental technology. Should work on Chrome 36, Firefox 48 and Opera 23.

Comment: yes, works on firefox 51. is there any workaround of this so that it works on all latest stable release browsers ? Most users won't have the nightly versions

Comment: @Towkir Don't think so. But CSS transitions have better browser support.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var timeInMs = 500;

document.getElementById("test").style.transition = "all "+timeInMs+"ms";
```

```css
#test {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='test' onclick="this.style.marginLeft = '50px';"></div>
```

I believe that this is what you are looking for, with no jQuery requirements.

EDIT: I have drafted a new version based on the comments below.

```js
var timeInMs = 500;

document.querySelectorAll("#test *").forEach(function(a){
  a.style.transition = "all "+timeInMs+"ms";
  a.addEventListener("click",function(){
    this.style.margin = 0;
    this.style.opacity = 0;
    this.style.width = 0;
  });
});
```

```css
#test * {
  background-color: green;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#test {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Assuming the OP is happy to add jQuery to his project then yes, `.animate()` is what he needs. Otherwise it is simple enough to implement the above with vanilla JS.

Comment: unfortunately no. I am looking for pure JS only. Thanks

Comment: @Towkir I have now edited the answer to have no jQuery. Does it work for you now?

Comment: @StardustGogeta actually it does, but in my case, I am trying to set the  `display:inline;` to `display:none;` with a transition via JS

Comment: @Towkir In that case, would it work to animate `opacity` and `width` to 0 instead?

Comment: @StardustGogeta `opacity:0` will still hold the required space of the element. I wanted something like "fadeOut and removed" effect.

Comment: You could also animate the width or height to 0 to shrink it.

Comment: @Towkir: It's not possible to animate display:inline to display:none. An animation needs values in between like margin:10px, margin:9px, margin:8px etc. until margin:0px. What's the in-between value between `inline` and `none`? Trying to animate `inline`, `inlin`,`inli`,`inl`,`in`,`i`,`n`,`no`,`non`,`none` produces invalid css values in-between. You have to be more creative. Change the opacity and height because both have in-between values.

Comment: @Towkir See my edit for an example of what I am saying.